# Why is this Ajax not working?

Tags: php, theme-development, admin, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure if I am abusing WordPress and Ajax by doing it this way but [WP and Ajax Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX) a well as [Plugin Development with Ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) do not seem to be very helpful. I have created the following Ajax situation:

```
(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
          var el = $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]');
          if(el.is(':checked')){
               el.prop('checked',false);   
          }
          $.ajax({
              url  : "<?php echo CORETHEME_ADMIN_TEMPLATE_HELPER_URL . 'UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php'; ?>",
              type : 'POST',
              data : { 'element_name' : el.prop('name') },      
              success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
              } 
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

Which states that: *When a link is clicked, we unchecked the check box and pass that element name to a class.*

Everything works until you see the `unset_package` method in my class

```
class CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_UncheckPackageThemeHelper{

    private $_element_name = null;

    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_POST["element_name"])){
            $this->_element_name = $_POST["element_name"];
            $this->unset_package();
        }
    }

    public function unset_package(){
        $option = get_option($this->_element_name);
        if(isset($option)){
            $option = '';
        }
    }
}

new CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_UncheckPackageThemeHelper();
```

Everything works until the `get_option` - I get 500 errors. meaning that the get_option() method doesnt exist - in this instance. **I think** If I take out the `get_option` and the rest of it and replace the contents of `unset_package`

with `echo json_encode($this->_element_name);` everything works and I get the element name given back.

Can some one explain why this isn't working and maybe show me the proper WordPress way? The Documentation was very confusing to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load a php file directly via an ajax request (`UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php`) it's loaded outside the context of WordPress, so no WordPress core functions are available.

All WordPress ajax requests should be routed through `admin-ajax.php`. You can print the URL with the function [`admin_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url):

```
admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
```

When `admin-ajax.php` is loaded, WordPress is bootstrapped, so you'll now have access to core functions.

The last step is to pass an `action` parameter from your javascript, and map that action to the function you want called when the action is executed:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```